# Passive voice / gerund object

Tags: passive-voice

> I go swimming once a week.

I am really confused whether to consider the ing form follows the verb go is **gerund or what**, because there are different views. Many pages and books tell = gerund. Oxford tells, **go swimming = intransitive.** Then, if it is a ( participle) the result of analyzing ( swimming ) should be = **complement**.

It is here a page :  It is very common to use a gerund after the verb "go" https://cutt.us/kCO49   Another result from the book :  **English Grammar and Composition Book for Competitive & Other Exams ... By Taniya Sachdeva ... This is as far as I know is one of the authoritative books page 241 ( Go + Gerund Combinations: e.g.: I go swimming every weekend. Would you ever go skydiving?  )**

**Have Fun: Learn To Speak and Understand American English: or What You Don't ...**
By Milena Kunin Portney

[image]

Comment: **go swimming** is an intransitive construction. **Swim the channel** would be a transitive example. Intransitive verbs do not have passive forms, inasmuch as with passives, the object of the verb is cast as the subject. There being no object, there is nothing to cast.

Comment: *Go* is not transitive in your example. Semantically, it’s roughly akin to the verb phrase “spend time.” (Of course, in that phrase, *spend* is transitive).

Comment: And *swimming* is not a gerund here, but a present participle.

Comment: Although *go* could also be paraphrased as “engage in.” And in that version, *swimming* **would** be a gerund.

Comment: To whom I add comment, I don't know ?   Is not ( swimming ) a noun here ?  Many grammar books and pages tell = noun  and object to the verb go .  at least, it is mentioned in this page  :  I like swimming ---The gerund swimming becomes the direct object. = the same to say I go swimming >>   some say  ( go swimming ) = phrasal verb ?      Here is the page I mentioned  ( I like swimming = gerund object ) https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-ecc-guidetowriting/chapter/gerunds/

Comment: Address a commenter by typing "@YosefBaskin" for example. Yes, "I like swimming" has a gerund. And by the way, passive is worth practicing, but in general it can introduce backward wording: "A good time was had by all" sounds like no one had fun other than robots.

Comment: The shortest (though awful) passive is "Swimming is performed by me once a week." Inshallah!

Comment: "@YosefBaskin  Good info I liked ....   Then in the sentence ( I go swimming )   Swimming, is what a part of speech?  Could you tell me please and analyze the sentence ?  Thank you in advance

Comment: @YosefBaskin, your passive would have come from “I perform swimming once a week.”

Comment: @AhmadMohammad, to see that *swimming* in your example is not a gerund (noun) but a participle (verb), compare it to “I go to swim once a week.”

Comment: @YosefBaskin,  I am not satisfied to say ( participle ) because all books tell = gerund  simply the participle can do the function of adjective  or a verb ..  so when analyze it do we say  I = subject   go = verb ,  swimming = verb  ?    not correct analyzing

Comment: Yes, "I go swimming" is like "I am swimming," a verb. The cartoon is wrong on this one.

Comment: @AhmadMohammad, you are right that in “I like swimming,” *swimming* is a gerund. And you can replace it with “the act of swimming” to form “l like the act of swimming.” But the example in your OP is different: we can’t say, *”I go the act of swimming.” Your original sentence is more like “When the pool is open, I go swim a few laps.”

Comment: @YosefBaskin  You said the cartoon is wrong  so let me change to another

Comment: @ Paul Tanenbaum 3  Please look at the photo I changed  It is clear said go + gerund

Comment: I should point out that we’ve been in quite a lengthy exchange about a very minor point, and there may not even be *a* single, right answer. In any event, this native speaker of American English is not convinced simply because some textbook says so. If you wish to consider it a gerund, you have my blessing to do so.

Comment: In your original example, "swimming" is a verb. See my answer below.

Comment: We don't allow posting images of text on SE because people who use screen readers won't see what's in the image, and someone searching for words in the image won't find them. So please remove the image and type in the relevant words to your question

Comment: Also, please avoid changing your question so much that it doesn't match its original form. A question should change very little once anyone has answered it.

Comment: Also, please don't argue with people or express personal opinions in the body of the question. The question space isn't for arguing.

Answer (score 3):

First point. Don't try to distinguish "gerund" from "participle".  There really is no consistent way to do so.  So when you read your text book, assume it uses the word "gerund" to mean "the **-ing** form of a verb", and not "a verb **used like a noun**".  **See below

Therefore "go swimming", is "go + the **-ing** form".

Is this an object? Well, one way to test this is to ask if the passive form is correct...  "Swimming was gone by me".  It's **not correct**, and so "swimming" is not the object of the verb go.

It is a complement, and "go" can take a variety of complements including nouns "go a day without food", adjectives  "go green with envy", and infinitives "go to watch the final".  In none of these examples is the complement an object, and none of them can be put into the passive voice.

---

Cambridge Grammar of the English Language  See pages 80-83 and 1220-1222

> Historically the gerund and present participle of traditional grammar have different sources, but in Modern English, the forms are identical. No verb shows any difference in form in the constructions of [14] and [19], not even be. The historical difference is of no relevance to the analysis of the current inflectional system […] This grammar also takes the view that even from the point of view of syntax (as opposed to inflection) the distinction between gerund and present participle is not viable, and we will therefore also not talk of gerund and present participle constructions

> 14: The train is now approaching Platform 3.
>
> The train approaching platform 3 is the 11.20 to Bath.
>
> 19: Destroying the files was a serious mistake.
>
> I regret destroying the files.

Comment: No, I don't agree with you this time because ( gerund is gerund and participle is participle ). Gerund can be noun. On the other hand, participle cannot be noun. Both can behave verbs Yes. But there is a huge difference between them.  Yes, some  writers would mention ing-form for both participle and gerund =  shortage in notes   Mostly the participle can do the function adjective and sometimes behaves as adverb. I know everything about these.  I am not a new learner.   Thank you that you helped me in past days.

Comment: What do you mean by "gerund can be noun".  This is like saying "cat can be dog".  Gerunds can be the subject of a sentence.  So can nouns.  But that doesn't mean gerunds *are* nouns. As Billj says in the other answer  "swimming" is a *verb* (not a noun)

Comment: If the  GERUND can be subject or object = noun because only nouns can do this function . Is it strange for you ?

Comment: @AhmadMohammad, No, it is not true that "only nouns can do this function".

Comment: For example prepostional phrases can be subjects "Under the bed needs cleaning"  Or adjectives "Heavy is the head that wears the crown."  And of course verbs/clauses in -ing and infinitive form can also be subjects.  So usually a noun phrase is the subject of a clause but not always.

Answer (score 2):

> *I go* [*swimming once a week*].

This is called a catenative construction, where "go" is the catenative verb and the bracketed subordinate clause is its catenative complement headed by the **verb** *swimming*.

We know that "swimming" is here a verb, not a noun, because it cannot be modified by an adjective, though it can be modified by an adverb, as in *I go leisurely swimming once a week*.

Now consider this example:

*I like swimming*

Here, the word "swimming" is ambiguous between a verb and a noun, though verb preferred (*I like to swim*). Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in *I like occasional swimming*, where *occasional swimming* is then the object of "like".

Comment: Thank you for your effort.   If it is with the verb ( like  \ love \ enjoy ) it is clear that the ing form  follows = object   I love swimming  \ I like swimming \ I like to go swimming | I enjoy swimming . No doubt swimming here = noun.  Even to compare it with Arabic = the same The matter with GO is complicated.   Even to say I go home . Some would say the verb GO = intransitive, so in  analyzing  if I draw  a diagram, what shall I  refer to ( swimming ) do I  write = verb , verbal, complement , or what ?

Comment: I disagree. In both "I love swimming" and "I like swimming", the word "swimming" is ambiguous between a verb and a noun (see my answer). In "I like to go swimming", "swimming" is a verb. In a  diagram, the "swimming" in "I like/love swimming" would preferably be labelled as a verb. But in "I like/love occasional swimming" it would be labelled as a noun

Comment: If the idea is about passive   Here people convert the following sentence into passive though the verb is intransitive  :  Active :  The sun rises from the east
Passive :   East is where the sun rises from

Comment: What about, "*I go **competitive** swimming* weekly."? "Competitive" is clearly an adjective modifying "swimming", so the adjective test doesn't work. The rephrasing-as-passive test still does though: **"Competitive swimming is gone weekly."*

Comment: @gotube I disagree, but in view of the unseemly conduct of the OP, I've no wish to become further involved.

Answer (score -1):

The ing form ( swimming ) = participle not a gerund for the reasons :

We cannot replace the pronoun ( it ) by the ing form.
I go it  = wrong

To compare "I go swimming" with ( I like swimming, I love swimming, I enjoy swimming ) we can replace ( it) by the ing form ( swimming )

I like it, I love it , I enjoy it  =  these forms objects here

Comment: As a test, this has problems. Consider the appositional use "We share a hobby, swimming."  That's grammatically sound and I think you'd say that the word "swimming" was a gerund (just as in "I like swimming") But "We share a hobby, it"  isn't correct, even if "swimming" has been mentioned before.  Perhaps you'd say that this is a particular aspect of the apposition, but I think my suggestion "Let's not try to distinguish different uses of -ing verbs" is simpler.

Comment: I from the beginning knew that it is participle, but because of many authors of grammar books whose explanations are wrong , I got confused.

Comment: Please don't use the answer section for arguing with other answerers. Just give your own answer, and if users think it's better, they'll upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

**I go swimming once a week.  swimming = participle and not gerund**

Simply of all what said, the **verb go = intransitive** so no gerund follows it.

Here are some methods:
Both the gerund and the present participle end in - ING. It is therefore important to distinguish between the two. **To make a clear distinction between gerunds and participles, use the possessive case of nouns and pronouns before gerunds.**

e.g. 'please forgive my sneaking in on you.' **The gerund functions as both a noun and a verb (verbal noun)**.
e.g. Teaching is an honorable profession'. While the present participle functions as an adjective and a verb (verbal adjective).

e.g. 'walking home, he sprained his leg.

Gerunds used as ordinary nouns have the determiner (**the**) used before and the preposition (of) used after it.

e.g. The voting of you, here in this page, is illegal.